# Efeito show e hide jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como faço pro jquery abrir apenas a box que cliquei, sem abrir as outras. Tentei usar $(this), mas eu não consegui. Não da maneira que quero.

> HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <i class="icon icon-edita">Editar</i>
    <div class="Box_editor">
        <p>Box editor 1</p>
    </div>

    <i class="icon icon-edita">Editar</i>
    <div class="Box_editor">
        <p>Box editor 2</p>
    </div>

    <i class="icon icon-edita">Editar</i>
    <div class="Box_editor">
        <p>Box editor 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

> JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".icon-edita").click(function(){
        $(".Box_editor").show("slow", function(){});
    });
});
```

> Não coloquei o css, pois já está correto o problema é no jquery msm. vlw o/

Comment: Cada `Editar` é suposto mostrar mostrar a `Box_editor` que está logo a seguir?

Comment: é sim isac. quando eu clicar no editar 1 a box 1 aparece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer mostrar a `Box_editor` a seguir a cada `.icon-edita` então tem de utilizar [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) para chegar ao elemento da frente, que é a box, e nesse fazer `show`. Da forma que tem com `$(".Box_editor").show(` acaba por mostrar todos.

Se pretende mostrar e voltar a esconder cada vez que clica então será melhor utilizar [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) em vez de `show`

Exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".icon-edita").click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.Box_editor {
  display:none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <i class="icon icon-edita">Editar</i>
    <div class="Box_editor">
        <p>Box editor 1</p>
    </div>

    <i class="icon icon-edita">Editar</i>
    <div class="Box_editor">
        <p>Box editor 2</p>
    </div>

    <i class="icon icon-edita">Editar</i>
    <div class="Box_editor">
        <p>Box editor 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu não sabia sobre o next() estava usando apenas (this), consegui aqui obg o/

Answer (score 1):

Acho que vc tem que usar assim: `$(this).find`

```
$('.icon-edita').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.Box_editor').addClass(".slow");
    return false;
});
```

Confere o nome das classes. Dessa forma quando vc clica no elemento com a classe `.icon-edita` ele vai adicionar a classe `.slow` só ele e não em todos que tem o mesmo nome da classe